# How do I make sprites bounce off the edge of the gameView in Android?

Tags: java, android, sprite

I've got this so far to try and reverse the velocity so they should theoretically go back on themselves but they don't.

```
 public void update() {
    if (x > gameView.getWidth() - bmp_width - xSpeed){
        xSpeed = xSpeed * -1;
        ySpeed = ySpeed * -1;
    }
    if (y > gameView.getHeight() - bmp_height - ySpeed){
        xSpeed = xSpeed * -1;;
        ySpeed = ySpeed * -1;;
    }
    if(x + xSpeed < 0){
        x = 0;
        xSpeed = 0;
        ySpeed = -5;
    }

    if(y + ySpeed < 0){
        y = 0;
        xSpeed = 5;
        ySpeed = 0;
    }
    x = x + xSpeed;
    y = y + ySpeed;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try commenting your own code and say what each line should do, you should be able to spot your errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
public void update() {
    x += xSpeed;
    y += ySpeed;

    if (x >= gameView.getWidth() - bmp_width){
        xSpeed = -xSpeed;
        x = gameView.getWidth() - bmp_width;
    }else if(x <= 0){
        xSpeed = -xSpeed;
        x = 0;
    }
    if (y >= gameView.getHeight() - bmp_height){
        ySpeed = -ySpeed;
        y = gameView.getHeight() - bmp_height;
    }else if(y <= 0){
        ySpeed = -ySpeed;
        y = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: So close, thank you, the sprites still exit the screen on the x-axis but can't see why since it's the same code for the y-axis

Comment: have you checked if the gameView.getWidth() returns the correct value?

Comment: It doesn't - Can't figure out where to change it either. The game width (in portrait) is larger than the height so I guess that's wrong